# Selinux semanage delete or modify chain

Tags: ssh, selinux

I  use on all my server port 24 for SSH. After change port i got error because Selinux block server SSHD restart

```
4 08:08:02 kvm452 sshd[18297]: error: Bind to port 24 on 0.0.0.0 failed: Permission denied.
May  4 08:08:02 kvm452 sshd[18297]: error: Bind to port 24 on :: failed: Permission denied.
May  4 08:08:02 kvm452 sshd[18297]: fatal: Cannot bind any address.
```

But if Selinux it's active (Centos 6.X) port 24 it's assigned to Cyrus

```
lmtp_port_t                    tcp      24
lmtp_port_t                    udp      24
```

Well I like change port for use port 24 with SSHD

```
semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp 24
    /usr/sbin/semanage: Port tcp/24 already defined
```

Try delete chain semanage 
    port -d -p tcp 24 /usr/sbin/semanage: 
        Port tcp/24 is defined in policy, cannot be deleted

Try several options, but i d'n't see solution. On manpage only say:

```
 -d, --delete
      Delete a OBJECT record NAME
```

Comment: Pick a different port. I recommend port 22.

Comment: Question it's about change port. I don't like use default port, and question it's about change port for security or personal questions. I not change port, not need ask. Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [non well-known port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers), something above 1024.

Comment: Question it's other. Question it's about SeLinux... not about sysadmin, and preferences on manage system.

Comment: It is still a sysadmin issue: SELinux administration depends on the port you are choosing. You simply can't use port 24 for SSH + SELinux, so for custom ports you have to follow industrial standards and choose a port > 1024.

Comment: Ok.. question .... how to modify or delete chain... not about " industrial standards" If you don't know work with selinux, please not comment. It's best for all.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `semanage port -m -t ssh_port_t -p tcp 24`?